# выполнение ahk скрипта только если активно нужное окно

Tags: autohotkey

как сделать выполнение скрипта, только если активно определенное окно,а если активные другие, то не выполняется скрипт?

```
#IfWinActive ahk_class Battlefield 3
SetTitleMatchMode, 2
LButton::RButton
```

будет работать как в нужном мне процессе, так и в браузере(мой компьютер), где в адресной строке будет Battlefield 3.

Answer (score 1):

Можно поставить условие по названию процесса:

```
#IfWinActive ahk_exe нужный_процесс.exe
```